# Why doesn't the select input field in my form get sent to the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form"
      action="/createstudent" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fieldName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">First name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fieldName" name="firstname">
        </div>
    </div>
  //....more input fields....

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="classof">Class of:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="classof">

        </select>
      </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var $select = $("#classof");
       var currentTime = new Date();
       var year = currentTime.getFullYear();

       for (var i=0;i<13;i++) {
            $select.append('<option value=' + (year + i) + '>' + (year + i) + '</option>');
        }
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, the options for the select input field, are populated dynamically, when the page loads. When I post my form (by clicking on the button), the request body contains the details of all the other fields (first name etc.), but there are no details of the select object... Why isn't it in the request body ?

Comment: You did not add name attribute to select field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `name` attribute on your select tag.

Answer (score 1):

Name attribute is missing here

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="classof">Class of:</label>
        <select class="form-control" id="classof" name="selected_item">

        </select>
      </div>
```